# ERC20 not recognized by TokenTracker

Tags: tokens, erc-20, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, openzeppelin-sdk

I have deployed ERC20 with reference to

*// File: openzeppelin- zos/contracts/token/ERC20/DetailedMintableToken.sol*

I called the initialized function with owner, name, symbol and decimal value. Everything went fine as I verified the parameters after deploying in Rinkeby Network.
But when I checked the contract in  Explorer it just showed as a normal contract, I was expecting it to show as an ERC20 contract. for eg:

***this is the contract I deployed ,without explorer detecting it as erc***

[image: this is the contract i deployed]

***and this is what i was expecting my contract to be displayed like***

[image]

> reference Rinkeby address1: 0x5238fFeAEdfc9481bd635B6E0e5eF3b05b19762a
>
> reference Rinkeby address2: 0x6e00e5bd453a6a5cf6eaa9d91f29de981730edfc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Etherscan will recognize your contract once it will log its first `Transfer` event.  This is how it works.  Though, even before the first `Transfer` event was logged, you may view your contract in token tracker: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tokens?q=0x5238fFeAEdfc9481bd635B6E0e5eF3b05b19762a

Comment: The same is true for ERC-721 tokens.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the tokens at least once first. Otherwise this will not work. Etherscan only recognises a contract as an token after its first `Transfer` event.

After sending the tokens once it should work perfectly!